# Vba Userform close while _Initialize

Tags: vba, userform

When I start my Userform, I first chack for a value. If this value is not existing the userform should close.

**Try1: UserForm_Inizialize**

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call languagePack
    '
    'initialize the userform
    '
End Sub
```

**Try1: function to choose a languagepack**

```
Private Sub languagePack()
    Dim LanguageItems(45) As String
    Dim Language_ID As Integer
    Language_ID = Outlook.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
    Call Language_AS.getLanguage(Language_ID, LanguageItems)
    If Not LanguageItems(0) = "" Then
        With Me
            '--write the array items into the userform objects and vaues
        End With
    Else
        MsgBox "It doesn't exist a Language-Pack for your language! Pleas change to english."
        Unload Advanced_Search ' will not work
    End If
End Sub
```

Try1 was to unload the userform in the function `languagePack()`, but didnt stop run and I get an error. So I tried another thing:

**Try2: UserForm_Inizialize**

```
Private close_userform As Boolean
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call languagePack
    If close_userform = Flase Then
        '
        'initialize the userform
        '
    else
        Unload Advanced_Search ' will not work
    end if
End Sub
```

**Try2: function to choose a languagepack**

```
Private Sub languagePack()
    Dim LanguageItems(45) As String
    Dim Language_ID As Integer
    Language_ID = Outlook.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
    Call Language_AS.getLanguage(Language_ID, LanguageItems)
    If Not LanguageItems(0) = "" Then
        With Me
            '
            '--write the array items into the userform objects and vaues
            '
        End With
        close_userform = False
    Else
        MsgBox "It doesn't exist a Language-Pack for your language! Pleas change to english."
        close_userform = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Whats wrong on Try2? The Boolean `close_userform` is global so both functions can read the value. But if it reachs the unload it happen nothing. After reaching the `end sub` I get an error.
The error is:
 Run-time error '91':
Objective variable or With block variable not set

**Macro that starts the Userform**

```
Sub start_Advanced_Search()
    Advanced_Search.Show (vbModeless)
End Sub
```

Pleas help me. Thanks for every command an answer. Kind regards, Nico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s the solution of my problem.
Thanks Tom for your help.

**Description:**
If there is no language pack for my Userform (I make the language packs), it will close the userform.
The function `languagePack()` returns a boolean (ture = language pack exists | false = no language pack exists).
This boolean is saved in `hasLanguage`. With the function `getHasLanguage()` I can get the value outside of the userform.
This function is used in the sub `start_Advanced_Search`. With the if function I check if there is a language pack, if not it will unload the userform.

**Userform**

```
Private hasLanguage As Boolean

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    hasLanguage = languagePack()
    If hasLanguage Then
        '
        'set the defaults...
        '
    End If
End Sub

Public Function getHasLanguage()
    getHasLanguage = hasLanguage
End Function

Private Function languagePack() As Boolean
    'array to save the new language
    Dim LanguageItems(49) As String 
    'this value will contain the LanguageID of Outlook
    Dim language_ID As Integer      
    'get LanguageID of Outlook
    language_ID = Outlook.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
    'call a sub to get the language
    Call Language_AS.getLanguage(language_ID, LanguageItems)
    'there is a languagepack if the first element of "LanguageItems" is not ""
    If Not LanguageItems(0) = "" Then
        With Me
            '
            'set the language of the userform
            '
        End With
        languagePack = True
    Else
        'there is no languagepack
        MsgBox "It doesn't exist a Language-Pack for your language! Pleas change to english."
        languagePack = False
    End If
End Function
```

**Modul**

```
Sub start_Advanced_Search()
    'start the userform
    Advanced_Search.Show (vbModeless)
    'use the get function
    If Not Advanced_Search.getHasLanguage() Then
        'unload if flase
        Unload Advanced_Search
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not make the languagePack sub a function that returns a  Boolean instead of writing the result to close_userform. Next use Unload Me instead Unload Advanced_Search

Comment: I changed it like you saied, but it don't work. Again the Run-time error '91'. I would poste my code, but with the two module's its something like 1200 lines and all commands in german (50% are commands).

Comment: If the sub languagePack is not in the code behind the form than I can understand why it would not work and give you the error 91 error. The code would see "Me' as a variable that has not yet been set. You could try to trace it and set a breakpoint at the With Me statement (if the compiles that is) I think the error is coming from that part of the code

Comment: The sub `LanguagePack` is in the userform. I tested it with `Me` and `Advanced_Search` (Advanced_Search is the name of the userform). I traced it and the userform do unload, no matter if `Me` or `Advanced_Search`, but when the program reach `end Sub` I get the error 91. That’s strange. Is it possible to activate a second `sub` after `UserForm_Initialize`? Maybe the type of sub is the problem. That the function type _Initialize need a userform.

Comment: It has to do with the initialize event. If the only line in your initialize event is unload me this will get you the same error. If you move the closing of the form (unload me) to the activate event this will work. Not ideal because activate will be triggered every time the form gets focus, but should be OK. Other option is to kill the macro completely by using End instead of Unload Me (I prefer to use me because it represents an instance of the userform. Advanced_Search could, in theory, trigger a new instance of the form)

Comment: I got a solution. Not exactly with your idea to use the `_Activate` but I create a private global value to save the output of `LanguagePack()` and I added a getter for this value. So I used this getter in the function `start_Advanced_Search` and unload the userform there if the userform gets no language. Will post the new code in a few minutes. Thanks allot Tom for your help.